# select2 multiselect drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been having trouble with my select2 forms i been up all night and cant figure it out. I have been trying to get multiselect boxes to work and I could only get the first few working. I have a feeling I got javascript erros but I cant think right now. please help me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Select2 3.1 - Tabbing out doesn&#39;t put placeholder back - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.js"></script>



      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css">



  <style type='text/css'>
    .selectContainer {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 200px;
}
  </style>





<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#e1').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Haircut Woman'}, {id:1, text:'Haircut Men'}, {id:2, text:'Haircut Children'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:4, text:'Hair Coloring'}, {id:5, text:'Tinting Semi/Permanent'}, {id:6, text:'Full Weave'}, {id:7, text:'Cap Frost'}, {id:8, text:'Partial Highlights/Lowlights'}, {id:9, text:'Single Foil'}, {id:10, text:'Color Gloss'}, {id:11, text:'Color Remove'}, {id:12, text:'Color Corrective'}, {id:13, text:'Reconstruction'}, {id:14, text:'Hair Styling'}, {id:15, text:'Shampoo and Style'}, {id:16, text:'Updo'}, {id:17, text:'Wedding Updo'}, {id:18, text:'Straightening'}, {id:19, text:'Deep Conditiong'}, {id:20, text:'Hair Texture'}, {id:21, text:'Inventive Perms'}, {id:21, text:'Body Waves'}, {id:22, text:'Hair Straightening'}, {id:23, text:'Chemical Straightening'}, {id:24, text:'Japanese Straightening'}, {id:25, text:'Karatin Blowout'}, {id:26, text:'Karatin Treatment'}, {id:27, text:'Hair Extension '}, {id:1, text:'Hair Extension Weaving'}, {id:2, text:'Single Hair Extension'}, {id:28, text:'Feather Hair Extension'}, {id:29, text:'Sparkle Extension'}],
    multiple: true
});



$('#e3').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Gel Full Set'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Fill'}, {id:2, text:'Gel Color'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Acrylic Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Acrylic Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Pink & White Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Paraffin Wax'}, {id:3, text:'Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'3D Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'French'}, {id:3, text:'Hand Polish Change'}],
    multiple: true
});


$('#e4').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Derm Renew Facial'}, {id:1, text:'Thermo Plastic Facial'}, {id:2, text:'Algomask +Cooling Thermo'}, {id:3, text:'Corrective Mask Facial'}, {id:3, text:'Collagen 90'}, {id:3, text:'Sea C Spa'}, {id:1, text:'Botinol “Botox like Effect”'}, {id:2, text:'Micro-Dermabrasion Treatment'}, {id:3, text:'Home Facial'}, {id:3, text:'European Facial'}, {id:3, text:'Dark Eye Circle & Puffiness'}, {id:3, text:'Acne Treatment Facial'}, {id:3, text:'Chemical Peel Treatment'}, {id:3, text:'Skin Tags, Brown Spot'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e5').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Lip'}, {id:2, text:'Chin'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}, {id:3, text:'Face'}, {id:3, text:'Half Legs'}, {id:3, text:'Full Legs'}, {id:3, text:'Under Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Half Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Full Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Bikini'}, {id:3, text:'Brazilian'}, {id:3, text:'Stomach'}, {id:3, text:'Back'}, {id:3, text:'Shoulder'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}],
    multiple: true
});


$('#e6').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Body Bronzing'}, {id:1, text:'Full Legs Bronzing'}, {id:2, text:'Sparkle Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:1, text:'Haircut Men'}, {id:2, text:'Haircut Children'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e7').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Bridal Make-Up'}, {id:1, text:'Make-Up Application'}, {id:2, text:'Lash or Brow Tinting'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Lash Perm'}, {id:3, text:'Flare Eye Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Single Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Airbrush Make-Up'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e8').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e9').select2({
    data: [{id:2, text:'15 Minutes'}{id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90 Minutes'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e10').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e11').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
    multiple: true
});

$('#e12').select2({
    data: [{id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Eyebrow Hair Stroke'}, {id:2, text:'Eye Liner'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Liner Upper & Lower'}, {id:4, text:'Lip Liner'}, {id:5, text:'FUll Lip'}, {id:6, text:'COrrective'}],
    multiple: true
});


});//]]>  

</script>



</head>


<body>
  <div class="selectContainer">
    <p>
        <label for="e1">Hair Service</label>
        <input type="text" id="e1" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e2">Nails Service</label>
        <input type="text" id="e2" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e3">Specialized Nails</label>
        <input type="text" id="e3" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
     <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e4">Skin Care</label>
        <input type="text" id="e4" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e5">Face & Body Waxing</label>
        <input type="text" id="e5" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e6">Body Bronzing</label>
        <input type="text" id="e6" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="e7">Cosmetic</label>
        <input type="text" id="e1" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e8">Massage</label>
        <input type="text" id="e2" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e9">Slimming & Toning Stomach Treatment</label>
        <input type="text" id="e3" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
     <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e10">Body Wrap</label>
        <input type="text" id="e4" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e11">Double Chin</label>
        <input type="text" id="e5" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e12">Permanent Make-Up Tattooing</label>
        <input type="text" id="e6" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle of this code will make people more likely to provide an answer, as diagnosing the issue will be easier that way than looking at a Big Block of Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is a syntax error when defining the array (missing comma), you should see it in the console.

```
$('#e9').select2({
    data: [{id:2, text:'15 Minutes'},{id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90 Minutes'}],
                                    ^___ This comma was missing
    multiple: true
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV23t/)**

Also make sure the id's of the last 5-6 selects are correct (seems like a copy paste issue)

Comment: thank you for the help. I cant seem to get all of them working though only 5 of them working.

Comment: @FouSaephan That probably is the copy paste issue, check your id for the last ones, they have incorrect ids.

Comment: ok i saw i was missing a part of my code. I put that in and now get an error debugger says SCRIPT1009: Expected '}' 
1, line 42 character 169

Comment: @FouSaephan i can't see your code. You should look up your code and check for console where the errors and see what is having a mismatch. Check the fiddle i have placed in my answer that has no issues.

Comment: sorry i have been trying to figure it out with console but have no idea how to fix it maybe its from lack of sleep but I just cant go to sleep until I finish this.... my code added was this

$('#e2').select2({
data: [{id:1, text:'Gel Manicure'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Pedicure'}, {id:2, text:'Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Sea Salt Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Deluxe Manicure}, {id:3, text:'Reflexology Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Express Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure w/Sea Salt'}, {id:3, text:'Deluxe Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Detox Foot Spa'}],
multiple: true
});

Comment: nevermind i think i got it thank you very much i appreciate ti

Comment: @FouSaephan cool if you got it resolved please do remember to mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting more than an hour I atlast found this in Select2 [Docs](https://select2.github.io/examples.html):

```
$('#profession').select2().val([1,2]).trigger("change")
```

here 1,2 is the value and #profession is the id of the select-option.

SHORT-SWEET-SIMPLE!